# Script to scale 9-patch images

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have a whole bunch of 9-patch images in xhdpi density and need to scale them down to hdpi, mdpi and ldpi. I know that the [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html) can do that, but only one at at time. I was wondering if there is a tool or script that i could use to scale them all at once. The only scripts that i've found can only scale normal images, not 9-patches. Any ideas?

Thanks Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the script from the following link. I use this all the time.
`http://neatocode.tumblr.com/post/34964277213/low-cost-phones`

Comment: It's not working 100% for me. It messes up the 9-patch borders, but i think that is fixable. I'll check again as soon as i have more time.

Answer (score 2):

[9patch-resizer](https://code.google.com/p/9patch-resizer/) will do bulk conversions with a nice drag and drop interface. You should be careful using this method because some images won't scale nicely using the naive algorithmic approach to all densities.

Comment: I found this tool before, but it does not seem to work on my Mac. It freezes as soon as i try to drag images into the UI...